# Use the result of a function in another on in python

Tags: python, function, attributes

If your str() or list() objects might end up being empty as so: astr = '' or alist = [], then you might want to use alist[-1:] instead of alist[-1] for object "sameness".

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
some_list[-1] = 5 # Set the last element
some_list[-2] = 3 # Set the second to last element
some_list
a_list = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
a_list[-1]
'three'
```

Comment: You don't define `self.c_s` in your `__init__()` of `Duct`. Also, why do you bother with the `__init__` when you are just overwriting the attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another better option is:

```py
class Duct:
    def __init__(self, width, height, L, Tair_inlet, Ts_int, hint, v_air, cp_air, rho_air):
        self.width = width 
        self.height = height 
        self.L = L
        self.Tair_inlet = Tair_inlet
        self.Ts_int = Ts_int
        self.hint = hint
        self.v_air = v_air
        self.cp_air = cp_air
        self.rho_air = rho_air
        self.c_s = EN.cross_section(self.width, self.height)

duct_ret = Duct(0.4, 0.3, 10, 18, 19.5, 3, 1, 1010, 1.2)
print(duct_ret.c_s)
print(EN.Tair_outlet(duct_ret.Ts_int, duct_ret.Tair_inlet, duct_ret.hint, duct_ret.c_s, duct_ret.v_air, duct_ret.rho_air, duct_ret.cp_air, duct_ret.L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to do this:

```py
duct_ret = Duct(0.4, 0.3, 10, 18, 19.5, 3, 1, 1010, 1.2)

#---- INPUT
#-- Geometry

import ENGINE as EN
duct_ret.c_s = EN.cross_section(duct_ret.width, duct_ret.height)
print(duct_ret.c_s)
print(EN.Tair_outlet(duct_ret.Ts_int, duct_ret.Tair_inlet, duct_ret.hint, duct_ret.c_s, duct_ret.v_air, duct_ret.rho_air, duct_ret.cp_air, duct_ret.L))
```